# How to read the following Itinerary

Tags: bookings

What do the abbreviations mean in the following itinerary:

```
  2  EK 641 L 29NOV 2 KBLDXB HK1       I  1630 1905   *1A/E*                   
  3  EK 344 L 29NOV 2 DXBKUL HK1       3  2140 0835+1 *1A/E*                   
  4  MH 704 V 30NOV 3 KULMNL HK1       M  1245 1630   *1A/E*                   
  5  UA 184 Y 01DEC 4 MNLGUM HK1       1  2255 0440+1 *1A/E*                   
  6  UA 155 Y 02DEC 5 GUMTKK HK1          0820 1008
```

especially, the numbers (2,2,3,4,5) before `KBLDXB`, `KULMNL`....
The letters and numbers before time (I, 3, M, 1)
`*1A/E*`?

Comment: A four day trip, in economy, from Kabul to Weno: you must be in a very specialized line of work. Or you have a terrible travel agent. ;)

Comment: Strange to see tabular data distributed without headers, thus asking this question.  I usually see exports into Excel (xls(x)) or CSV formats, and also with PDF and/or Web (HTML/CSS) visually-styled presentation as well.

Seems pretty unprofessional.

Comment: @Pysis This is (an excerpt) of the raw PNR that would be printed on paper for a passenger who wanted it. Changing the presentation often obscures the information that the passenger needs.

Comment: @Pysis the itineraries I received from airlines are often written in contracted headlines that I can't understand

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Like abbreviated headlines?

Comment: @Pysis yes, like CL, NVB, NVA...

Answer (score 45):

Reading from left to right:

`2` is the segment number on your itinerary. Segment 1 is used as a header.

`EK 641` is the flight prefix and number. This is Emirates flight 641.

`L` is the booking class for this sector. `L` is often a midprice economy booking class.

`29NOV` is the departure date, in the time zone of the departure airport.

`2`: The numbers after the date are days of the week. 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday, etc.

`KBLDXB` is the origin and departure airport codes concatenated. This is a flight from Kabul to Dubai.

`HK1` is the flight status. `HK` means your reservation is confirmed. `1` means it is confirmed for one passenger.

`I`: The letter or number before the time is the departing terminal, in this case the International terminal at Kabul. On the next flight it is terminal `M` from Kuala Lumpur.

`1630` the departure time at Kabul, local time.

`1905` the arrival time at Dubai, local (Dubai) time. Sometimes you will see a `+1` to indicate that the local time is one day ahead of the date at the time and place of departure.

`*1A/E*` is a tag indicating that the sector is eligible to be printed on an eticket instead of a paper ticket.

Comment: I think "segment" 1 is used for a header row

Comment: Just a note: `*1A/E*` is not the only way to signal that it can be printed on an e-ticket, as 1A is Amadeus (one of the two biggest GDS in the world, the other being 1S: Sabre). I don't know if `*1S/E*` is a thing as Google is quite unhelpful...

Answer (score 9):

5  UA 184 Y 01DEC 4 MNLGUM HK1       1  2255 0440+1 *1A/E*

```
5: Segment 5
UA 184: United Airlines Flight 184
Y: fare class (pricey economy)
4: Thursday
MNLGUM: Manila to Guam
HK1: one confirmed seat
1: Terminal 1 (I think)
2255: departs 10:55 pm
0440+1: arrives 4:40am the next day
*1A/E* : Amadeus e-ticket
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/453536-how-read-codes-pnr.html).

1A/E* = 1A/Amadeus, E* = E-ticketable segment.

Comment: I have summarised the relevant info!