# How do I read this Qantas itinerary change info?

Tags: itineraries, qantas

I think this looks okay....but is it?

```
3  QF 012 S 22DEC 6 JFKSYD TK2       8  1800 0835+2 *1A/E*    (time was at 18:00 08:30)
4  QF 922 S 28DEC 5 SYDCNS TK2       3  0920 1120   *1A/E*    (time was at 09:35 11:35)
5  QF 703 L 01JAN 2 CNSMEL TK2       2  1305 1735   *1A/E*    (time was at 11:20 15:45)
6  QF 093 L 04JAN 5 MELLAX HK2       2  1040 0610   *1A/E*
7  QF 011 L 04JAN 5 LAXJFK HK2       B  0820 1630   *1A/E*
```

Comment: Perhaps edit to say what you think and what you are stuck with?

Comment: Thank you! So, the first three lines show arr/departure timing changes on those three flights. I see no problem with the new times. Am I correct?

Comment: "I see no problem with the new times. Am I correct?": You haven't given us any information about your schedule, so it's hard to know whether the new times will be a problem or not.  Or, perhaps I should say, what kinds of problems were you thinking about in asking the question?

Comment: You should remove the booking codes from the posting. Anyone in the world can log in with them and cancel or rebook your flights.

Comment: @Aganju: There don't seem to be any "booking codes" here. If you're referring to `JFKSYD`, etc, those are the _routes_: `JFK` (John F. Kennedy International, New York, USA) to `SYD` (Sydney, New South Wales, Australia).

Comment: you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems OK. There's a slight change in timings in the first three sectors, hence the 'TK' code which indicates that a confirmed sector has changed times, instead of the 'HK' which is the default code for confirmed sector.

Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This is my first time here and I am quite happy to join. Hope to contribute and help answer questions soon myself.

Comment: @EllenScordato You can upvote the answer if you like it (click the up arrow next to the answer) and accept the answer the as well (click the tick mark).

Answer (score 2):

As you've guessed, this is your flight itinary. It is in [PNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record) notation, a format that airlines and travel agents use for data exchange. There is an [online tool that decodes it](https://www.pnrconverter.com/).

There is already another [answer on how to decode the fields](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83118/how-to-read-the-following-itinerary/83121) - your case "TK2" means "timing change on this flight". Form the original times you have given, the first two segments only changed slightly, the third (number 5) will be almost 2 hours later than originally planned.

If that's okay is up to you. If you're not happy, you could reach out to Qantas if they'd re-book you onto another flight.